# Regular Expression to extract a value between curly brackets

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with a lot of comma-separated URL parameters in a bigquery table.

Most of the URL parameters contain ifmobile and ifnotmobile values in curly brackets.

I would like to extract these and write them in separate columns. But the values and lengths are not definite, but they are always in curly brackets and start with ifnotmobile or ifmobile.

Here some examples:

**URL Parameter**

1. `{"track":"{ifnotmobile:-215181}{ifmobile:-1039775}"}`
2. `{"track":"{ifmobile:-1173731}{ifnotmobile:-1173730}"}`
3. `{"nccoupon":"%2B5PRDKCLV","track":"{ifmobile:-1029110}{ifnotmobile:159860}"}`

In these three examples, I would like to have two new columns with all ifmobile and all ifnotmobile values.

**Extracted Values**

**Column ifnotmobile**

1. -215181
2. -1173730
3. 159860

**Column ifmobile**

1. -1039775
2. -1173731
3. -1029110

I am very happy for any help I can get.
I tired it already with some REGEXP_EXTRACT, but I failed.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT params, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(params, r'{ifnotmobile:(.*?)}') AS ifnotmobile,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(params, r'{ifmobile:(.*?)}') AS ifmobile
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your example as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{"track":"{ifnotmobile:-215181}{ifmobile:-1039775}"}' params UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"track":"{ifmobile:-1173731}{ifnotmobile:-1173730}"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"nccoupon":"%2B5PRDKCLV","track":"{ifmobile:-1029110}{ifnotmobile:159860}"}' 
)
SELECT params, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(params, r'{ifnotmobile:(.*?)}') AS ifnotmobile,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(params, r'{ifmobile:(.*?)}') AS ifmobile
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row params                                                                          ifnotmobile ifmobile     
1   {"track":"{ifnotmobile:-215181}{ifmobile:-1039775}"}                            -215181     -1039775     
2   {"track":"{ifmobile:-1173731}{ifnotmobile:-1173730}"}                           -1173730    -1173731     
3   {"nccoupon":"%2B5PRDKCLV","track":"{ifmobile:-1029110}{ifnotmobile:159860}"}    159860      -1029110
```

Note: you can case extracted values into whatever type you need  - likely INT64